# Are Google Apps Script execution timeouts different for trigger executions and editor executions?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timeout

I have a Google Sheets budgeting spreadsheet that uses the javascript functionality to automatically add a new sheet for each week (based on the current date when the spreadsheet is opened). I have been using iterations of this script for years now.

Just recently the script started timing out on me. [EDIT: In the past I have used this same script to add and update multiple sheets at a time. Now I can't seem to add even one sucessfully.] However, if I open the script editor and run the function from there, it works perfectly. In the execution log I can see that a trigger execution times out at about 30sec, but an editor execution works every time, and takes about 40sec.

While typing this, I noticed on Google's quotas there is a 30sec runtime limit per custom function. Why is it different when triggered from the editor?

Comment: From [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations): "The limits shown below are provided solely to assist you in testing scripts. All limits are subject to elimination, reduction, or change at any time, without notice." I think that's them saying "because we said so."

Comment: Hmm. . . yeah. . .

Comment: Is your script in V8 runtime version?

Comment: It wasn't, but when I noticed that it wasn't finishing properly, I opened the editor and saw the V8 message, and I switched over. So as of the time of the OP, yes, it was in V8. It seems to be behaving the same way in V8 as it was before I switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [offical quota limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) Apps Script scripts (i.e those run from the script editor or with a trigger like `onEdit()` ) have a timeout limitation of 6 minutes per execution while custom functions just have a timeout limitation of 30 seconds per execution.

These [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) are Apps Script functions created to be used in the SpreadSheet as formulas and therefore they run differently and have a different timeout time per execution.

Comment: Yes, that does help me some. I wasn't aware that when I created a function it was intended to be used in the spreadsheet as a formula. I was only trying to follow good coding etiquette by creating and calling functions, but maybe I can strip the code down to eliminate the custom functions. . .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to have onOpen() create a new menu item where I can manually initiate the custom function, so the 30 second timeout is no longer an issue. I'm still not sure why it wasn't happening until recently. Maybe I added enough budget lines that the process got too long? But this serves my purposes just fine!

Comment: Yes, so if you use an ```onOpen()``` trigger you will get the 6 minute timeout as you are not calling the Apps Script function from a Spreadsheet custom formula (instead you are calling the function from the Menu bar). Anyway, I'm glad I was helpful :D